# junit assertEquals ignore case

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, junit4

im just moving from c# -> java. I need to write some tests using junit. 
In my test i need to compare two strings to see if they match.
So we also have the Assert.assertEquals, but this is case sensitive. How can i make it case insensitive?
What i need is:

```
"blabla".equals("BlabLA")
```

to return true.

So in C#, we used to have :

```
public static void AreEqual (
    string expected,
    string actual,
    bool ignoreCase,
    string message
)
```

I was quickly going thru Junit docs, but i can't seem to find anything like this.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I find that [Hamcrest](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/) provides must better assertions than the default `JUnit` asserts. Hamcrest gives MANY MANY more options and provides better messages on failure. Some basic `Hamcrest` matchers are built into `JUnit` and `JUnit` has the [assertThat](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertThat%28T,%20org.hamcrest.Matcher%29) built in so this is not something totally new. See the `hamcrest.core` package in the `JUnit` API [here](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/). Try [IsEqualIgnoringCase](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/text/IsEqualIgnoringCase.html) which would look like this.

```
assertThat(myString, IsEqualIgnoringCase.equalToIgnoringCase(expected));
```

With static imports this would be

```
assertThat(myString, equalToIgnoringCase(expected));
```

if you want to get really fancy you would do:

```
assertThat(myString, is(equalToIgnoringCase(expected)));
```

One of the advantages of this is that a failure would state that `expected someString but was someOtherString`. As opposed to `expected true got false` when using `assertTrue`.

Comment: Sry, i am very new to java, any clue why i am getting this? Seems to be correct import.. 

1) AddNewTrip(PikoFuncTests.Tests.Trip.AddNewTripTest)
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hamcrest.Matcher.describeMismatch(Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/hamcrest/Description;)V
 at org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:18)
 at org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:8)
 at PikoFuncTests.PageObjects.MainView.Trip.TripMainView.ValidateResultsTable(TripMainView.java:147)

Comment: This usually happens when you have imported 2 different versions of Hamcrest. There is one that is included in JUnit so if you included hamcrest-all to get the functionality there might be a delta. Try using junit-dep instead of junit. The -dep version does not come with Hamcrest so your Hamcrest import will be the only one.

Comment: Here is a post that describes the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869711/getting-nosuchmethoderror-org-hamcrest-matcher-describemismatch-when-running

Answer (score 17):

Use

```
"blabla".equalsIgnoreCase("BlabLA") use for check equality ignore case
```

Then you can use

```
 assertTrue("blabla".equalsIgnoreCase("BlabLA"))
```

Comment: It assertTrue(s1.equalsIgnoreCase(s2)); that's it

Answer (score 5):

There is no direct support for this assert in `JUnit` (assuming you are using JUnit of course), but you could use:

```
assertTrue("blabla".equalsIgnoreCase("BlabLA"))
```

It may be worth wrapping this in a separate helper method which provides a sensible failure message if they don't match (look at the docs for `assertTrue` to see how this could be done).

Comment: No worries - though check out @JohnB answer I think this will give better results (i.e. better output if the test fails) as well as being arguably more readable.

Answer (score 5):

What about:

```
assertEquals("blabla","BlabLA".toLowerCase());
```

or

```
assertEquals(expectedLowerCaseString,actualString.toLowerCase());
```

Then you can still see the difference if they are not equal.

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked at the [`String` JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29) ?

```
"blabla".equalsIgnoreCase("BlabLA")
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `assertTrue(s1.equalsIgnoreCase(s2))`

Answer (score 3):

Consider [AssertJ](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/) (previously FEST) for your assertions, it's been my favorite assertion API for tests for years:

```
assertThat("blabla").isEqualToIgnoringCase("BlabLA");
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the `equalsIgnoreCase` from the [string](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29) doc: