# Java junit testing with assertions on objects

Tags: java

```
public class DatatypeTest {

    private static final Log logger = LogFactory
            .getLog(TreeConstantTest.class);

    @Test
    public void testDatatypeFromName()
    {
        Datatype d= Datatype.fromString("Profile");

        assertTrue((d.toString().compareToIgnoreCase("PROFILE") == 0));

    }
     @Test
     public void testDatatypeFromName1()
     {
         Datatype d = Datatype.fromString("SupportDetail");
         assertTrue((d.toString().compareToIgnoreCase("SUPPORT_DETAIL") == 0 ));
     }
}
```

When i execute the first test case it is showing failure case in green.

But when i execute the second test case it is showing me the error as `java.lang.AssertionError`.

I am writing the test cases for this class

public enum DocDatatype {

```
PROFILE("Profile"),

SUPPORT_DETAIL("SupportDetail"),
```

Comment: The string `"SupportDetail"` does not match the string `"SUPPORT_DETAIL"`, even if you ignore case. The second one has an underscore in it.

Comment: public enum DocDatatype {

 PROFILE("Profile"),

 SUPPORT_DETAIL("SupportDetail"),
I am writing test case for this class

Comment: If you're saying that this ought to be true based on your enum, then include the enum code in your question.

Comment: `AssertionError`, being a `Throwable`, can give you a detailed message of the underlying cause of the error. You should examine that.

Comment: The bit of `enum` code you've posted doesn't include the definitions of `fromString` or `toString`, which are the things your unit test is checking.

Comment: java.lang.AssertionError
 at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:86)
 at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:41)
 at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:52)
 at com.canon.cusa.newweb.orm.inet.test.DocDatatypeTest.testDocDatatypeFromName1(DocDatatypeTest.java:37)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is that the question is lacking some context. And the use-case for this DataType class is a bit strange (DataType should be the enum).

```
public enum DataType {

PROFILE("Profile"),
SUPPORT_DETAIL("SupportDetail");

private String value;
private DataType(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.value;
}
}
```

Your do not really need this `fromString`-method. Look at this class:

```
public class DataTypeUtil {

public static DataType fromString(String value) {
    return DataType.valueOf(value.toUpperCase()); // should check for null or blank
   }
}
```

Then you can do your test like this, note the 3'rd test-method:

```
public class DataTypeTest {

@Test
public void testDatatypeFromName() {
    DataType d = DataTypeUtil.fromString("Profile");
    assertTrue((d.toString().compareToIgnoreCase(DataType.PROFILE.toString()) == 0));
}

@Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
public void testDatatypeFromInvalidName()   {
    DataType d = DataTypeUtil.fromString("SupportDetail");
    assertFalse((d.toString().compareToIgnoreCase(DataType.SUPPORT_DETAIL.toString()) == 0));
}    

@Test
public void testDatatypeFromCorrectName()   {
    DataType d = DataTypeUtil.fromString("Support_Detail");
    assertTrue((d.toString().compareToIgnoreCase(DataType.SUPPORT_DETAIL.toString()) == 0));
}

@Test
public void testGetValueFromEnum() throws Exception {
    DataType dataType = DataType.valueOf("Profile".toUpperCase());
    assertTrue(dataType == DataType.PROFILE);
}
```

}

Note the `valueOf`-method. It does exactly what your `fromString`-method does, and it is available to you from the `enum`.

Main point is that you only need your `enum` and `DataType` is your best bet.

Hope this clarifies your problem somehow :)

*Edit:*

If I should guess your use-case, you have a document which has a certain format or type. Why not create a `Document` class with `DataType` as an enum field on the object?

Regards,
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the ability to see the actual value.

You can go in with a debugger, but that's not a good solution: what if your test is run by an automated system?

You need to change your assertion into something that will provide more information.

Please look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17652051/junit-assertequals-ignore-case) for JUnit way to assert equalsIgnoreCase.

Another way is to provide a failure message:

```
assertTrue("Unexpected result: + d.toString(), "SUPPORT_DETAIL".compareToIgnoreCase(d.toString()) == 0 ));
```

Comment: DOC Datatype Constants
public enum DocDatatype {
PROFILE("Profile"),
SUPPORT_DETAIL("SupportDetail"),

 
 String name;

 DocDatatype(String name) {
  this.name = name;
 }

 public String getName() {
  return name;
 }

 public String toString() {
  return name;
 }
 public static DocDatatype fromString(String value) {
  for (DocDatatype type : DocDatatype.values()) {
   if (type.getName().equals(value))
    return type;
  }

  throw new java.lang.IllegalArgumentException(value
    + " is Not valid dmDataType");
 }
}