# Junit Testing for the enum class

Tags: java, junit

```
public enum DivisionConstant {
    consumer(1), office(2), production_printing(3);
}
```

For this enum I wrote a  junit test as:

```
@Test
public void testDivisionConstantFromInt()
{
    DivisionConstant d  = DivisionConstant.fromInt(1);
    assertTrue((d.toName().compareToIgnoreCase("consumer") ==  0));
}
```

When I execute this it shows only true or false. But I want to know if the test case won't work I want to the reason for the failure of the test

Comment: Use something like the hamcrest assertions: `assertThat(d.toName, is("consumer"))`, to get more expressive error messages.

Comment: possible duplicate of [junit assertEquals ignore case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17652051/junit-assertequals-ignore-case)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This you need to supply yourself

```
assertTrue("Name was not lexically identical to \"consumer\"", 
       d.toName().compareToIgnoreCase("consumer") ==  0);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use custom messages, like this:

```
assertTrue("Value of d["+d+"] is not equal to consumer", (d.toName().compareToIgnoreCase("consumer") == 0));
```