# Classpath issue with JUnit 4.12

Tags: maven, classloader, junit4

I've got JUnit 4.12 in my pom and I keep getting the following:

> [ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.util.SurefireReflectionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hamcrest/SelfDescribing

Here is the surefire config:
The only thing that's fixed it is setting theadCount=0.  This forces an isolated classloader, but if I force an isolated classloader through other settings but a threadCount>0 it fails again.

I've got hamcrest in my dependencies properly.  Not sure where to go with this at this point.

```xml
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                    </includes>

                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
                        <version>1.3</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: You should also add hamcrest to the surefire plugin dependencies

Comment: @orid I tried, and updated the above.  No luck.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7869711/944849) may be useful. Since reading it years ago I no longer use '-all' dependencies.

Comment: try junit version 4.11