# Can't import org.hamcrest.Matchers in test files

Tags: java, maven, junit, hamcrest

I'm trying to use hamcrest to create some tests, but I can't seem to get maven to include whatever is needed for `org.hamcrest.Matchers.*` to be resolved.  I've seen a number of questions, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869711/getting-nosuchmethoderror-org-hamcrest-matcher-describemismatch-when-running), that imply there is some sort of dependency issue with importing hamcrest, junit, and mockito, but I've fooled around with my `pom.xml` file and no matter what I try I can't get it to work.

Here's the dependency section of my `pom.xml`.  What do I need to do to get hamcrest to resolve properly?

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
        <artifactId>jira-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jira.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Add dependency on jira-core if you want access to JIRA implementation classes as well as the sanctioned API. -->
    <!-- This is not normally recommended, but may be required eg when migrating a plugin originally developed against JIRA 4.x -->
    <!--
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
        <artifactId>jira-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jira.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>atlassian-spring-scanner-annotation</artifactId>
        <version>${atlassian.spring.scanner.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>atlassian-spring-scanner-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>${atlassian.spring.scanner.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- WIRED TEST RUNNER DEPENDENCIES -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>atlassian-plugins-osgi-testrunner</artifactId>
        <version>${plugin.testrunner.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2-atlassian-1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Uncomment to use TestKit in your project. Details at https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/jira-testkit -->
    <!-- You can read more about TestKit at https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/Plugin+Tutorial+-+Smarter+integration+testing+with+TestKit -->
    <!--
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.jira.tests</groupId>
        <artifactId>jira-testkit-client</artifactId>
        <version>${testkit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.19</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.powermock/powermock-module-junit4 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.powermock/powermock-api-mockito -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-all -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-collections</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20180813</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>fluent-hc</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.plugins.rest</groupId>
        <artifactId>atlassian-rest-common</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.sal</groupId>
        <artifactId>sal-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wink</groupId>
        <artifactId>wink-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3-incubating</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: As a note, your dependencies are rather badly out of date.

Comment: I know. I'm building for a fairly old version of Jira. That's one of the reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to replace the `mockito-all` dependency with `mockito-core`. Mockito-all includes an old version of hamcrest, which is known to cause issues. See e.g. [mockito/issues/324](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/324)